# OpenSuse 12.3 gpu fan speed

Tags: power-management, gpu, fan, temperature, opensuse

I won't go into the details of what I tried and simply explain what I want.

graphics card: AMD HD 4870

So I'm usually working with Windows 7 and my gpu is at 54C with 30% fan speed when idle. 
Now I regularly need to use Linux, specifically OpenSuse [12.3] 
(I'm a Linux newbie). 
The fan is running at full speed with the gpu being at 64.5C - again when idle - 
how is that possible. Is the standard driver that bad? 
I get a lot of tearing in 2D, too. 
On several websites it was recommended to use the standard driver and 
not the proprietary AMD driver, especially since there seem to be 
incompatibilities with version 12.3 of OpenSuse.

Is there a fix for my problem?

Comment: It is possible that you are running a program that uses OpenCL.  OpenCL allows your GPU to do work that would otherwise run on the CPU.  I also use OpenSuse, but 13.1 is there a reason you didn't upgrade?

Comment: A significant number of issues can be resolved by upgrading to the newest version of packages.  From the command line:  **yast online_update** will update your existing packages, but not upgrade you to 13.1.  You can download the 13.1 ISO from the website and burn it to DVD and upgrade that way.

Comment: It was a clean install I did a few weeks ago, no OpenCL running. I will attempt the upgrade and report back.

Comment: I did a clean install (format) and installed all updates. Same issue. I use the KDE desktop if that is relevant.

Comment: I found this: https://forums.opensuse.org/blogs/malcolmlewis/package-day-systemd-radeon-power_profile-142/ (accessed in google cache) Not sure if and how I can use it.

Comment: So after some more research I found that a simple boot parameter did the trick. Add radeon.dpm=1 to the optional parameters in the bootloader in yast. The temperature dropped by 9°C. Marvelous! Now I can finally work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing OpenSuSE 13.1 a simple boot parameter did the trick for me. 
Add **radeon.dpm=1** to the optional parameters in the *Bootloader* in *YaST*. 
The temperature of my gpu dropped by 9°C while idle (thus the fan is running much slower, too).